# Unable to fetch api data in recyclerView

Tags: android, api, kotlin, android-recyclerview, retrofit

Api data is not fetching in the recyclerView of MovieFragment.The app is running no error is shown but in recyclerView of movieFragment the api data is not visible. I am unable to find the error, please help me with this.

My MovieFragmment is

```
const val  BASE_URL ="my api url was pasted here"
class MovieFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentMovieBinding
    private lateinit var movieAdapter: MovieAdapter
    private val movieList = mutableListOf<Movie>()

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentMovieBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.rv.setHasFixedSize(true)

        binding.rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        movieAdapter = MovieAdapter(requireContext(), movieList)
        binding.rv.adapter = movieAdapter

        getData2()
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun getData2() {
        val retrofitBuilder = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
            .create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        val retrofitData = retrofitBuilder.getData()

        retrofitData.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Movie>?> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Movie>?>,
                response: Response<List<Movie>?>
            ) {
                val responseBody = response.body()!!
                movieList.addAll(responseBody)
                movieAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Movie>?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("MovieFragment", "onFailure: " + t.message)
            }
        })
}
```

My MovieAdapter is

```
class MovieAdapter (val context: Context,val movieList: List<Movie>):RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    class ViewHolder(itemView:View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var binding:MovieItemBinding=MovieItemBinding.bind(itemView)

        var movie_title:TextView=binding.movieTitle
        var movie_release_year:TextView = binding.movieReleaseYear
        var movie_runtime:TextView = binding.movieRuntime
        var movie_cast:TextView = binding.movieCast
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var itemView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.movie_item,parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.movie_title.text = movieList[position].Title
        holder.movie_release_year.text = movieList[position].Year
        holder.movie_runtime.text = movieList[position].Runtime
        holder.movie_cast.text = movieList[position].Cast
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return movieList.size
    }
}
```

My responseData is

```
data class ResponseData(
@SerializedName("Movie List")
val movieList: List<Movie>
)
```

My Movie data is (model)

```
data class Movie(
    val Cast: String,
    val Director: String,
    val Genres: String,
    val IMDBID: String,
    @SerializedName("Movie Poster")
    val moviePoster: String,
    val Rating: String,
    val Runtime: String,
    @SerializedName("Short Summary")
    val shortSummary: String,
    val Summary: String,
    val Title: String,
    val Writers: String,
    val Year: String,
    @SerializedName("YouTube Trailer")
    val youTubeTrailer: String
)
```

My ApiInterface is

```
interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("1.json")
    fun getData(): Call<List<Movie>>
}
```

My json is

```
{
    "Movie List": [
        {
            "Title": "The Redeemed and the Dominant: Fittest on Earth",
            "Year": "2018",
            "Summary": "In 2017 the fittest athletes on Earth took on the unknown and unknowable during four of the most intense days of competition in CrossFit Games history. \"The Redeemed and the Dominant: Fittest on Earth \" captures all the drama as top athletes resembling chiseled Grecian gods descend on Madison, Wisconsin, to face a series of trials. Hercules faced 12; they take on 13. Emotions run high as a throng of Australian athletes rise to the top. By the end of the competition, some learn tough lessons-that all that glitters isn't gold, or even bronze-and some learn that they're even stronger than they realized. The best among them enter the pantheon of CrossFit giants and earn the right to call themselves the \"Fittest on Earth.\"",
            "Short Summary": "In 2017 the fittest athletes on Earth took on the unknown and unknowable during four of the most intense days of competition in CrossFit Games history. &quot;The Redeemed and the Dominant: ...",
            "Genres": "Documentary",
            "IMDBID": "tt8144778",
            "Runtime": "119",
            "YouTube Trailer": "rlZ5MG-E2Ls",
            "Rating": "7.1",
            "Movie Poster": "https://picsum.photos/1280/720",
            "Director": "Heber Cannon",
            "Writers": "Heber Cannon",
            "Cast": "Dave Castro|Justin Bergh"
        },
        {
            "Title": "The Redeemed and the Dominant: Fittest on Earth",
            "Year": "2018",
            "Summary": "In 2017 the fittest athletes on Earth took on the unknown and unknowable during four of the most intense days of competition in CrossFit Games history. \"The Redeemed and the Dominant: Fittest on Earth \" captures all the drama as top athletes resembling chiseled Grecian gods descend on Madison, Wisconsin, to face a series of trials. Hercules faced 12; they take on 13. Emotions run high as a throng of Australian athletes rise to the top. By the end of the competition, some learn tough lessons-that all that glitters isn't gold, or even bronze-and some learn that they're even stronger than they realized. The best among them enter the pantheon of CrossFit giants and earn the right to call themselves the \"Fittest on Earth.\"",
            "Short Summary": "In 2017 the fittest athletes on Earth took on the unknown and unknowable during four of the most intense days of competition in CrossFit Games history. &quot;The Redeemed and the Dominant: ...",
            "Genres": "Documentary",
            "IMDBID": "tt8144778",
            "Runtime": "119",
            "YouTube Trailer": "rlZ5MG-E2Ls",
            "Rating": "7.1",
            "Movie Poster": "https://picsum.photos/1280/720",
            "Director": "Heber Cannon",
            "Writers": "Heber Cannon",
            "Cast": "Dave Castro|Justin Bergh"
        }
]
}
```

Comment: 1st Must be check your API get response in Postman or not

Comment: You can put a break-point into the line of `movieList.addAll(responseBody)` then check your movie list.

Comment: try to clear movies list before addAll -movieslist.clearAll()- See if it works